# Backend на Java

Tags: java, backend

Доброе время суток. Начал учиться backend, но видео-курс на ютубе не до конца закончен и у меня осталась пара вопросов. "Учитель" все уроки работал лишь с одним классом "MyServlet.java", который наследовался от HTTPServlet и имел два метода GET и POST ( насчёт этих методов понятно). Например, при регистрации пользователь передаёт некоторые данные

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Регистрация</title>
</head>
<body> 
 <form method = "POST" action ="MyServlet">
 Имя<input type = "text" name = "name">
 Возраст<input type ="text" name = "age">
 Электронная почта<input type = "text" name = "email">
 <input type = "submit" value = "Зарегистрировать">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Далее в методе POST берутся эти параметры и пользователь регистрируется

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String age = request.getParameter("age");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
```

А если мы с другой html страницы хотим передать совсем другие параметры? Получается для каждой страницы писать свой java класс со своими GET и POST и указывать в html класс и метод?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Информация пользователя</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form method = "METHOD" action = "CLASS">
 .....
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, если использовать чистые сервлеты, то на каждый адрес надо писать свой сервлет(класс). Это можно заметить по файлу `web.xml` или аннотациям над сервлетами.

Один класс может содержать только по одному методу `doGet`, `doPost`, `doPut`..., дублирование методов внутри класса не позволит компилятор. Соответственно на каждый адрес пишется свой сервлет.

Можно использовать Spring. Он использует сервлеты, но вам не надо будет создавать кучу классов. Используя аннотацию `@RequestMapping` можно задать и метод запроса и адрес, который будет случать метод.

Comment: Получается регистрировать драйвер и получать соединение нужно в каждом классе по-новому?

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH какой драйвер?

Comment: DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());

Comment: sql это отдельная вещь. Можете завести синглентон класс и получать из него DriverManager. Если будете использовать spring, то там есть инъекция зависимостей - спринг сам создаст DriverManager и положит его в ваш класс

Comment: Если без спринга, посмотрите на паттерн команд. Создание набор команд, мапите на него пути и дальше только парсите пути.